# Blazor Server Side app won't redirect to login page after IIS WebSite is restarted

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-5

After I restart IIS Website, I get following error, instead of being redirected to login page:

```
blazor.server.js:1 POST https://localhost/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 net::ERR_ABORTED 401
```

[image: screenshot]

when visiting https://localhost/someblazorroute.

I need to manually go to https://localhost/ and hard reload the page (in chrome Ctrl+Shift+R) in order to be redirected to login

I have following startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => options.AutomaticAuthentication = false);

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout";
            })
            .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler >("Basic", null);

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowBasicAuthPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("Basic");
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub().RequireAuthorization();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does the issue only happens on IIS server, not on dev environment?

Comment: @FeiHan: Yes, not on dev environment (kestrel). I'm not sure about IIS Express, because it only happens when I visit not default route first, and VS opens the app with default route after F5

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact same issue and the solution to this was rather trivial.

you just need to ensure that you call for setting up Authentication, Authorization and then set default route in the right order in startup.cs as shown in the code below:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        .
        .
        .

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();


        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        
        //this MUST come after the lines before.
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```